# convert GCCRandom(Mersenne Twister by Takuji Nishimura and Makoto Matsumoto) to stl random

Tags: c++, random, stl

I am trying to translate the book Game Coding Complete by Mike McShaffry 4E to modern C++17 standard and faced with the code of Mersenne Twister by Takuji Nishimura and Makoto Matsumoto.
Is it right to convert random generator code from book like that:

from:

```
#include <ctime>
#define CMATH_N 624
#define CMATH_M 397
#define CMATH_MATRIX_A 0x9908b0df   /* constant vector a */
#define CMATH_UPPER_MASK 0x80000000 /* most significant w-r bits */
#define CMATH_LOWER_MASK 0x7fffffff /* least significant r bits */
#define CMATH_TEMPERING_MASK_B 0x9d2c5680
#define CMATH_TEMPERING_MASK_C 0xefc60000
#define CMATH_TEMPERING_SHIFT_U(y)  (y >> 11)
#define CMATH_TEMPERING_SHIFT_S(y)  (y << 7)
#define CMATH_TEMPERING_SHIFT_T(y)  (y << 15)
#define CMATH_TEMPERING_SHIFT_L(y)  (y >> 18)
typedef int INT;
typedef unsigned int UINT;
#define MAXUINT ((UINT)~((UINT)0))
#define MAXINT ((INT)(MAXUINT >> 1))
class GCCRandom {
private:
    unsigned int rseed;
    unsigned int rseed_sp;
    unsigned long mt[CMATH_N]; /* the array for the state vector  */
    int mti; /* mti==N+1 means mt[N] is not initialized */
public:
    GCCRandom() {
        rseed = 1;
        rseed_sp = 0;
        mti = CMATH_N + 1;
    }
    unsigned int Random(unsigned int n) {
        unsigned long y;
        static unsigned long mag01[2] = { 0x0, CMATH_MATRIX_A };
        if (n == 0)
            return(0);
        if (mti >= CMATH_N) { /* generate N words at one time */
            int kk;
            if (mti == CMATH_N + 1)   /* if sgenrand() has not been called, */
                SetRandomSeed(4357); /* a default initial seed is used   */
            for (kk = 0; kk < CMATH_N - CMATH_M; kk++) {
                y = (mt[kk] & CMATH_UPPER_MASK) | (mt[kk + 1] & CMATH_LOWER_MASK);
                mt[kk] = mt[kk + CMATH_M] ^ (y >> 1) ^ mag01[y & 0x1];
            }
            for (; kk < CMATH_N - 1; kk++) {
                y = (mt[kk] & CMATH_UPPER_MASK) | (mt[kk + 1] & CMATH_LOWER_MASK);
                mt[kk] = mt[kk + (CMATH_M - CMATH_N)] ^ (y >> 1) ^ mag01[y & 0x1];
            }
            y = (mt[CMATH_N - 1] & CMATH_UPPER_MASK) | (mt[0] & CMATH_LOWER_MASK);
            mt[CMATH_N - 1] = mt[CMATH_M - 1] ^ (y >> 1) ^ mag01[y & 0x1];
            mti = 0;
        }
        y = mt[mti++];
        y ^= CMATH_TEMPERING_SHIFT_U(y);
        y ^= CMATH_TEMPERING_SHIFT_S(y) & CMATH_TEMPERING_MASK_B;
        y ^= CMATH_TEMPERING_SHIFT_T(y) & CMATH_TEMPERING_MASK_C;
        y ^= CMATH_TEMPERING_SHIFT_L(y);
        return (y % n);
    }
    float Random() {
        float r = (float)Random(MAXINT);
        float divisor = (float)MAXINT;
        return (r / divisor);
    }
    void SetRandomSeed(unsigned int n) {
        /* setting initial seeds to mt[N] using         */
        /* the generator Line 25 of Table 1 in          */
        /* [KNUTH 1981, The Art of Computer Programming */
        /*    Vol. 2 (2nd Ed.), pp102]                  */
        mt[0] = n & 0xffffffff;
        for (mti = 1; mti < CMATH_N; mti++)
            mt[mti] = (69069 * mt[mti - 1]) & 0xffffffff;
        rseed = n;
    }
    unsigned int GetRandomSeed() {
        return rseed;
    }
    void Randomize() {
        SetRandomSeed((unsigned int)time(NULL));
    }
};
```

to code with std::mt19937 engine and std::uniform_int_distribution:

```
#include <random>
#include <limits>
#include <chrono>
class MTRandom {
private:
    unsigned int m_rseed = 1;
    unsigned int m_rseed_sp = 0;
    static const unsigned int MAXINT = std::numeric_limits<int>::max();
    std::mt19937 m_engine;
public:
    MTRandom() { m_engine.seed(m_rseed); }
    unsigned int Random(unsigned int n) {
        std::uniform_int_distribution<unsigned int> distr(0, n);
        return distr(m_engine);
    };
    float Random() {
        std::uniform_real_distribution<float> distr(0.0f, 1.0f);
        return distr(m_engine);        
    }
    void SetRandomSeed(unsigned int n) {
        m_engine.seed(n);
        m_rseed = n;
    }
    unsigned int GetRandomSeed() {
        return m_rseed;
    }
    void Randomize() {
        SetRandomSeed((unsigned int)std::chrono::system_clock::to_time_t(std::chrono::system_clock::now()));
    }
};
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The short answer is (mostly) yes. Your use of C++17 and std::mt19937 looks mostly correct.

However:

- You have `std::uniform_int_distribution<unsigned int> distr(0, n)`, and this generates random values from `0` to `n` inclusive. Your original code appears to generate values from `0` to `n-1` inclusive. So you should use `std::uniform_int_distribution<unsigned int> distr(0, n-1)`. In addition, before doing that, you would need to check whether `n` equals zero:

  ```
  unsigned int Random(unsigned int n) {
      if (n == 0)
          return 0;
      std::uniform_int_distribution<unsigned int> distr(0, n-1);
      return distr(m_engine);
  };
  ```
- Your code declares `m_rseed_sp` and `MAXINT`, both of which are not used. It would be better to remove them. Then you can also remove `#include <limits>`.
- It is probably slightly more efficient to create member variables for std::uniform_int_distribution and for std::uniform_real_distribution. For std::uniform_real_distribution this is trivial because you never change the parameters of the distribution. For std::uniform_int_distribution, it is *slightly* more complicated because now you have to create parameters and pass them to the distribution. Something like this (untested):

  ```
  private:
      using IntDistribution = std::uniform_int_distribution<unsigned int>;
      IntDistribution m_int_distribution;

  public:
      unsigned int Random(unsigned int n) {
          if (n == 0)
              return 0;
          IntDistribution::param_type parameters{0, n-1};
          return m_int_distribution(m_engine, parameters);
      };
  ```
- For the `Randomize()` function, you might consider something like this instead:

  ```
  void Randomize() {
      std::random_device randomDevice;
      SetRandomSeed(randomDevice());
  }
  ```

  Ideally, this seems better than just using the current time. However, I've seen rumors that `std::random_device` is not implemented well on a few platforms, so maybe what you have is better? That's a judgement call.
- Note: There is no guarantee that std::mt19937 will initialize its internal state identically to the way your old code did, in fact I think it is very unlikely. So you can't expect identical output even if you use the same seed.